# Mount encrypted ChromeOS partition in Chrubuntu

Tags: data-recovery, ecryptfs, chrome-os

I have a Samsung Chromebook 2, and was using crouton to run linux in a chroot next to ChromeOS and ran out of SDD space. I opened `gparted`, and it told me that the GPT table was in the wrong place and that there were ~500 megs of unpartitioned space at the end of the drive.

I decided to take the MicroSD card out of my Android phone and flash Chrubuntu on to it, and make a backup. I was stupid and put the backup in the `~/Downloads` folder, which is encrypted with some kind of encryption related to my Google password. I then booted Chrubuntu from the SD card and moved the partition table and expanded the stateful partition to allow for more space.

I then rebooted, but the Chromebook firmware didn't like the new partition layout. Normally I would just use a USB recovery stick, but I really want to get the SD card backup back because my a lot of my Android apps have stopped working because of the absence of the SD card. Also, I have a few files stored in the `Downloads` folder that I would like to recover.

Looking at the Chromium project page, it seems that they are encrypted with some multi-layer mess of encryption involving `ecryptfs`. I mounted the stateful partition from Chrubuntu and found a file in the root called `encrypted.block` and `encrypted.key`. This is where my knowledge stops. I can't seem to find out how to mount the `encrypted.block` file, but I believe that it has something to do with my google password. The `encrypted.key` file just shows up as two lines of

```
�^�7��,3Y^�k^Y
```

in `nano`. I think that the password has something to do with my google password hash, but I can't seem to figure out what. Can someone help me to recover the data?

EDIT: Just to clarify, the problem is that I can't figure out how to mount the partition. I know it has something to do with my Google password, which I know, but I am not sure how to derive the encrypted partition password from it.

Comment: I realize I'm a little late to this, but I was researching the same thing. I picked up a used 16GB SSD and wanted to see what was on it before I blew it away. From what I've found so far, the file encrypted.key is itself encrypted with a key that's held in the NVRAM of the device it came from, and access and decoding of that key involves something regarding verifying secure boot and the state of the TPM.